# create a new variable based on other using R

Tags: r, database, dataframe, variables, var

I have a dataframe with 2 key variables and I want to create a third one based on existing one, my data:

| Qi | age |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 56 |
| 5 | 62 |
| 4 | 24 |
| 2 | 46 |

I want to create a variable called "general_capitale" if:

Qi == 1 "general_capitale" takes a random number between 0 and 6;

Qi == 2 "general_capitale" takes a random number between 6 and 12;

Qi == 3 "general_capitale" take either  14, 15, 17 or 20;

And 0 otherwise,

Any ideas please

Comment: `df$general_capitale <- (
  (df$Qi == 1) * sample(0:6, nrow(df), replace = TRUE) +
    (df$Qi == 2) * sample(6:12, nrow(df), replace = TRUE) +
    (df$Qi == 3) * sample(c(14, 15, 17, 20), nrow(df), replace = TRUE) 
)
`

Comment: @Aurèle You should post your [comment as an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment).

Answer (score 1):

In base R:

```r
set.seed(100)
dat$general_capitale = 0
dat$general_capitale[dat$Qi==1]  = sample(0:6, length(dat$general_capitale[dat$Qi==1]), replace = TRUE)
dat$general_capitale[dat$Qi==2]  = sample(6:12, length(dat$general_capitale[dat$Qi==2]), replace = TRUE)
dat$general_capitale[dat$Qi==3]  = sample(c(14,15,17,20), length(dat$general_capitale[dat$Qi==2]), replace = TRUE)

dat
#   Qi age general_capitale
# 1  1  56                2
# 2  5  62                0
# 3  4  24                0
# 4  2  46               12
```

I have assumed by "random number" you mean random integer within range from a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 0):

```
df$general_capitale <- ( 0L +
  (df$Qi == 1) * sample(0:6, nrow(df), replace = TRUE) +
    (df$Qi == 2) * sample(6:12, nrow(df), replace = TRUE) +
    (df$Qi == 3) * sample(c(14L, 15L, 17L, 20L), nrow(df), replace = TRUE) 
)
```